# Odoo 10 project version

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I'm trying to port [Project issue](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/project_issue/) module from Odoo 8 to Odoo 10 to add version field to projects.

project_version.py :

```
class project_version(models.Model):
   _inherit = 'project.project'
   _name = "project.version"
   _order = "name desc"
   _columns = {
      'name': fields.char('Version Number', required=True),
      'active': fields.boolean('Active', required=False),
   }
   _defaults = {
      'active': 1,
   }
```

When I try to install it, Odoo say

```
Model not found: project.project.version

Error context:
View `project_version list`
[view_id: 750, xml_id: n/a, model: project.project.version, parent_id: n/a]
None" while parsing file:///c:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Odoo%2010.0/server/custom/project_task_version/views/views.xml:9, near
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="project_version.list">
      <field name="name">project_version list</field>
      <field name="model">project.version</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree>
          <field name="name"/>
          <field name="active"/>
        </tree>
      </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: Just uncomment the record in XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means, that Odoo can't find you model. As I see, you set name "project.version" to you model, but Odoo searching for "project.project.version". So, just try to change name of model from "project.version" to "project.project.version".
Next:
This type of declaration of model now is not supported by Odoo 10:

> _columns = {
>         'name': fields.char('Version Number', required=True),
>         'active': fields.boolean('Active', required=False),    }

Try to look at this documentation - https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html#model-fields

Answer (score 0):

You must replace the declaration _columns and _default by the following: these being used by you is from old API syntax.

The syntax about your field attributes should be like this:

```
name = fields.Char('Version Number', required=True)
active = fields.Boolean('Active', required=True, default=True)
```